# How to screen quotes for Cytoscape Web

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, quotes, cytoscape

I'm trying to use quoted text in one of node's attributes:

```
var network_json = {
    dataSchema: {
        nodes: [ { name: "label", type: "string" },
                 { name: "foo", type: "string" }
        ]
    },
    data: {
        nodes: [ { id: "1", label: "1", foo: "Text without quotes" },
                 { id: "2", label: "2", foo: "Some \"quoted\" text" }
        ]
    }
};
vis.draw({network: network_json});
```

And then making listeners for each node:

```
vis.addListener("click", "nodes", function(event) {
    alert(event.target);
})
```

But I've got "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error while clicking on a node with quoted text.
How should I screen quotes there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who have same problem, it's a bug.
They promise they would fix it in next stable release.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cytoscapeweb-discuss/GWU0deOaaRs/discussion

They send fixed swf to email by request.